# Android custom dialog method

Tags: android, dialog

Can someone tell me why cannot i call `setOnClickListener` method on my buton in custom dialog method? Is there a possible way to handle clicks in this kind of dialog? Here's the code:

```
private Dialog wifiDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wifi_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Upload");

    Button no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_wifi_No);
    Button yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_wifi_Yes);

    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // runtimeException

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wifiDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
private Dialog wifiDialog(Context context) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wifi_dialog,null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.setTitle("Upload");

    Button no = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_wifi_No);
    Button yes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_wifi_Yes);

    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

And use :

```
wifiDialog(this); // In activity context;
```

I explain you why you getting error. You cycle your logic. In `onClick` method you try to create another dialog and set same `click listener` to the same `button`. SO if you want to dismiss your dialog use the instanse of dialog, instead of creation new.

Comment: Please don't just post code with no explanation of what you changed and why, or the OP (and future visitors) learn nothing.

Comment: @Simon Sorry. I will take that into consideration